# Get Node nodeType list programatically (xml.dom.minidom.Node)

Tags: python, dom

So I realize that the docs have the list of node types for the Node class, but from poking around, I can't seem to find a way to programmatically get a list of available `nodeType`s for a given Node object (short of inspecting the class, pulling every all caps member with a name ending in 'NODE', and then sorting by value).  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I suggest that you remove the nodeType as tag. I guess it is about xml.dom.minidom. so xml.dom should be fine

Comment: Are you looking for their numeric values? They are [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1950641247)

Comment: @thg435 No, I meant mapping the other way.  I know the constants are named class members, but Node.nodeType returns an int, so if you want to make the nodeType human readable, you need a convenient way to map the indices back to names.  I was hoping there was something like that built in, but it looks not.

Comment: If I knew of a mechanism that would make for an illustrative code example, I wouldn't be asking the question in the first place.  Besides, I already provided an example of the solution I was trying to avoid as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish there was something better, but lacking that, I created a new module:

```
from xml.dom import Node
from collections import OrderedDict

if not hasattr(Node, 'get_all_node_types'):

    @classmethod
    def get_all_node_types(cls, refresh=False):

        if not hasattr(cls, '_type_dict') or refresh:
            unsorted_types = {getattr(cls, name) : name for name in dir(cls) if name.endswith('_NODE')}
            cls._type_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(unsorted_types.items(), key = lambda t : t[0]))
        return cls._type_dict

    setattr(Node, 'get_all_node_types', get_all_node_types)
```

It's hacky, so I don't really like it, but as long as it is imported at least once during program execution, I get my new method.

Comment: For anyone just wanting the list here's the output formatted as JSON:
 
`{ "1": "ELEMENT_NODE", "2": "ATTRIBUTE_NODE", "3": "TEXT_NODE", "4": "CDATA_SECTION_NODE", "5": "ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE", "6": "ENTITY_NODE", "7": "PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE", "8": "COMMENT_NODE", "9": "DOCUMENT_NODE", "10": "DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE", "11": "DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE", "12": "NOTATION_NODE" }`